# Multimodule project with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am converting my standard java project to maven and at the same time I am setting it up in eclipse. The first thing that stroke me was that in multimodule project (and I suppose every serious java application is multimodule) as mine looks hard to work with. I am using [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html) approach and the problem is do I have to always type "mvn install" so that all the shared projects are built and installed into repository so that other projects will work with their's new version?

It seems a little bit overcomplicated. Why the mvn eclipse plugin doesn't support something like creating "eclipse project dependencies" to ease up eclipse development?

Answer (score 1):

well... sorry for this question. mvn eclipse plugin does exactly what I described.